# How to insert a stop watch before the polling starts

Tags: java

May I know How to insert a stop watch for this piece of code from `Poll()` method...I have to make start count such that before the database starts and amount of time it took for polling.

```
    public void poll() throws Exception {
    st = conn.createStatement();

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        Timestamp start;
        rs = st.executeQuery( "select * from msg_new_to_bde" );
        Timestamp end;
        //speed = end - start;


        Collection<KpiMessage> pojoCol = new ArrayList<KpiMessage>();
        while (rs.next()) {             
            KpiMessage filedClass = convertRecordsetToPojo(rs);
            pojoCol.add(filedClass);

        }
        for (KpiMessage pojoClass : pojoCol) {
            System.out.println("=== Iteratioin Nr. " + i + "====");
            System.out.print(pojoClass.getSequence());
            System.out.print(pojoClass.getTableName());
            System.out.print(pojoClass.getEntryTime());
            System.out.print(pojoClass.getProcessingTime());
            System.out.println(pojoClass.getStatus());
            //            System.out.println(pojoClass.getprocessDuration());
        }
        System.out.print(pojoCol.size());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use currentTimeMillis() function:

Before launch polling:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

After Polling execution:

```
long stop= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Execution time is stop - start in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `System.currentTimeMillis` is what you looking for.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// 
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println((endTime  - startTime) + "ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();    
Timestamp start = new Timestamp(date.getTime());    
//process    
java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date();    
Timestamp end = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
rs = st.executeQuery( "select * from msg_new_to_bde" );
long stop= System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("execution time: " +stop-start + " ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
timeThisMethod();
long end = System.nanoTime();

long howLongDidItTake = end - start;
```

This method is more precise then System.currentTimeMillis()

Citation from java API :

> Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer,
>   in nanoseconds.